# Need to learn about Video stitching

Tags: video, video-editor, signal-processing

I need to start learning about video stitching. I have studied about this and have some knowledge that the video should be converted into image sequences, then image alignment is done [geometric and photometric correction], and feature matching is used to match two video frames which are then blended together.

I don't know whether this is correct and I need to know if this process is correct and is there anything I missed? Is there anything I need to learn? Also I need to learn from basics. I want some knowledge about this.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example of what you're looking to do? There are lots of papers from SIGGRAPH on topics like this, but I'm not sure which ones to point you towards because it's not clear what your goal is.

Comment: http://www.airpano.com/360-videos.php

Comment: Note a video is a image sequence so expanding it into individual files or reading individual frames from a stream is the same thing in a different wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I've found 2 useful references:

LEVIN, A., ZOMET, A., PELEG, S., AND WEISS, Y. 2004. [Seamless image stitching in the gradient domain.](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~levina/papers/eccv04-blending.pdf) In European Conference on Computer Vision, 377–389.

and

PÉREZ, P., GANGNET, M., AND BLAKE, A. 2003. [Poisson image editing.](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf) ACM Transactions on Graphics (SIGGRAPH ’03), 313– 318.